# Which Dom operation is slower?

Tags: javascript, dom

*(both img and parent element position:absolute)*

Moving the image to new co-ordinates.

or

Changing the .src of the img. (to a much smaller file)

?

just curious.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends very much. How about profiling it both ways?

Comment: @deceze Both profiles seem pretty much the same, however, i'm testing the page on a local network with a fast pc. Not exactly internet realistic atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe changing the source of the img tag will trigger a GET request. I would say that is the more expensive operation.